# Как правильно сделать сортировку списка list?

Tags: c++, stl

У меня есть список list с объектами класса Student.
Вот сам класс:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    string clas;
    string dateBirth;
public:
    student(string name_m, int age_m, string class_m,string dateBirth);
    ~student() {};
    void show();
    friend ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const student& strudent_m);
    string getName();
    string getClas();
    
};


#include "Student.h"


student::student (string name_m, int age_m, string class_m, string dateBirth_m)
{
    this->name = name_m;
    this->age = age_m;
    this->clas = class_m;
    this->dateBirth = dateBirth_m;

}
ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const student& strudent_m)
{
    out <<  strudent_m.name << endl;
    out <<  strudent_m.dateBirth << endl;
    out <<  strudent_m.age << endl;
    out <<  strudent_m.clas<< endl;
    return out;
}
string student::getName()
{
    return (this->name);
}
string student::getClas()
{
    return (this->clas);
}

void student:: show()
{
    cout<<"Имя фамилия ученика: " <<this->name << endl;
    cout << "Дата рождения: " << this->dateBirth << endl;
    cout << "Возраст: " << this->age << " лет"<<endl;
    cout << "Класс обучения: " << this->clas << endl;
}
```

Хочу сделать сортировку по переменной string clas. Гуглил эту тему. Написал компаратор, почему то вылетает с ошибкой "Invailed comparator".  Вот мой код, которым я пытался сравнивать:

```
bool compare_clas(student& first,  student& second)//Компаратор сам
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        if (first.getClas()[i] < second.getClas()[i])
            return true;
        else  if (first.getClas()[i] > second.getClas()[i])
            return false;
        ++i;
    }
    return true;
}

  list1.sort( compare_clas);
        list<student>::iterator it = list1.begin();
        for (list<student>::iterator it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end(); ++it)
            (*it).show();
        break;
```

Comment: @wololo изменил, не помогло. Все так же вылетает

Comment: Потому что неправильно изменил. Во-первых, у тебя в логике баг - сколько раз по-твоему выполняется цикл? Во-вторых, что будет если сравнить элемент с собой?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сравнить по первым двум символам строк?

Comment: @wololo да, там их всего 2. То есть в каком классе учится ученик 9А или там 9Б. Вот по этим 2-м символам и идет сравнение

Comment: Тогда в качестве тела компаратора достаточно написать `return first.getClas() < second.getClas();`.

Comment: @wololo да спасибо, в самом начале так же писал. Думал может из-за этого ошибка. А оказалась из за константых ссыылок

Comment: @wololo как вы сказали не вышло. Потому что он почему то считал, что 9Г больше, чем 11А. Пришлось написать свой компаратор.

Comment: Да, потому что строки сравниваются посимвольно, и символ `9` больше чем символ `1`. Чтобы учитывать числа внутри строк, нужны некоторые дополнительные манипуляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что твой компаратор всегда возвращает true.
А должен возвращать true только если первый меньше.

И ещё ты вместо const-ссылок написал обычные, но VS тебе это порстила.

Comment: @Qewtiy если я пишу const ссылки, то он не дает применить метод GetClass()

Comment: Поменяй его сигнатуру на `string student::getClas() const`.

Comment: @Iskander ну а почему этот ваш метод не является константным? Он меняет ваш объект? Что-то мне так не кажется

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не меняет, просто значение возвращает, но я не указал его, как константый

Comment: @Iskander оттого и проблемы